# Can not be loaded because it comes from a more recent Sirius release

Tags: eclipse, papyrus, eclipse-sirius, sirius

I have a problem opening a project in my own computer. So in the first time i created this project on my pc, than put it on git i went to the university i continued working on it and when i re-pulled the version of my project which is after modifying it on the university's computer trying to open it i encountered this problem :

An internal error occurred during: "Loading models".
The modeling project "FIL" is invalid: Problem during loading models:
The Sirius resource (platform:/resource/FIL/model/fIL.aird) can not be loaded because it comes from a more recent Sirius release.

Representation version is: 15.0.0.202209061200

Last Sirius migration version is: 15.0.0.202201261500

I assume it's because of versions differences between the sirius used on those 2 different computer , i didn't find how to update or change the version in my personal computer. Can you please help me ?

Thank you , and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

re-installing the sirius from the market is a solution for that.